An 'autopsy-esque table' or 'autopsy table-esque table'?
In this sentence I drafted, I am unsure if the modifier 'autopsy-esque' is correct or not for a table:

At the funeral home in Suzhou, the body of my friend was placed on an autopsy-esque table, in a yellow body bag, before cosmetic embalming. The mother of the deceased entered the room, and when the bag was unzipped for her, she burst into tears beside the table towards her drowned young daughter's pale face.

Or should it be 'an autopsy table-esque table'? It sounds awkward to my EFL ears. How do I idiomatically append the suffix '-esque' to the two-word phrase 'autopsy table'?
I was told that 'an autopsy-style table' would be a better fit. However, I thought appending the word 'style' to 'autopsy' seems misleading because it should be used to modify the table or the whole phrase rather than the modifier of the table 'autopsy'.
If neither are idiomatic, how can I rewrite the snippet while preserving the 'autopsy table' in the sentence? I want to keep that phrase because it is the first thing that comes to my mind when recalling this scene.

-style certainly sounds better than -esque to me. Why not simply embalming table? A quick Google search also shows dressing table.

It sounds awkward to anyone's ears. You can't just tack -esque onto any adjectivally-qualified noun phrase and expect it to sound natural. The full OED says The words formed with this suffix on English nouns are chiefly nonce-words of a jocular character, as cigaresque. Other formations separately noticed include Audenesque, Bramantesque, Browningesque, Caravagg(i)esque, Carlylesque, Chaplinesque, Dantonesque, Dickensesque, Disneyesque, Macaulayesque, Turneresque (which you'll note are all derived from proper nouns, not common noun phrases such as autopsy table).

@PeterKirkpatrick Oh, I don't know if it was an embalming table or not. It seemed like an autopsy table.

From the context you've given we're in a funeral home and the body is placed in a room in anticipation of the embalming process. It makes sense to describe the table in that light. An embalming table is a natural expression. (Note also that embalming and autopsy are different processes. An autopsy is forensic in purpose. An English speaker would not expect it to take place in a funeral home.)

@PeterKirkpatrick - also, to Brits, an autopsy is something that happens to dead Americans, in a morgue. If we need it, we have a post-mortem in a mortuary.

@MichaelHarvey, good point. I've clearly been watching too many CSI episodes...

I’m voting to close this question because I have got the answer in the comments.

@PeterKirkpatrick OK. Thanks!

an autopsy-like table.

There are many ways to say it:

an autopsy-like table
an autopsy kind of table
an autopsy-ish table
an autopsy-looking table

